# Information about VisualStudio Light Switch

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-lightswitch

Microsoft announced they are going to launch VisualStudio lightswitch 2011, can any one explain what is the exact use of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/lightswitch/gg702208

Answer (score 0):

It is easiest way to develop business application using Microsoft technology where by you can achieve majority of day to day life functionality.

Even more it has inbuilt export functionality to office and comes with hosting option to desktop, web and cloud.